# After using Set::extract not getting associative data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am trying to get json data without model name, so here I have tried extract like below code

```
$transaction = $this->Transaction->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Transaction.user_id'=>$id)));
$transaction = Set::extract('/Transaction/.', $transaction);
```

Problem is now I am not getting associative data in json output. Here is the json look like

```
[{"id":"130","transaction_type":"1","user_id":"44","entry_by":"pitocms","added_id":"25","perticuler":"test","Volume":null,"per_unit":null,"credit_money":"1500","debit_money":"0","balance":"-1500","created":"2015-12-27 21:21:11","modified":"2015-12-27 21:21:11"}]
```

There has actually 2 model transaction and user.

Comment: For future questions, please always add a dump of the data that you are working on, and also show what exactly you'd like the data to look like in the end, as guessing what you have and what you want is rather counter productive - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set::extract()` does exactly that, it creates a new array after extracting selected data from a source array. Therefore, in order to obtain user information, you will have to extract it too:

```
$data = $this->Transaction->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Transaction.user_id'=>$id)));
$transactions = Set::extract('/Transaction/.', $data);
$users = Set::extract('/User/.', $data);
```

As stated by @ndm in the comments, class `Set` has been long deprecated in favour of class `Hash`. You can achieve the same with:

```
$data = $this->Transaction->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Transaction.user_id'=>$id)));        
$transactions = Hash::extract($data,'{n}.Transaction');
$users = Hash::extract($data,'{n}.User');
```